# How to Copy(Automatically Insert) a Value From a Input form to a JS File

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting some value through a form . But unable to automatically insert that value in a separate js file.

**Details :**

i am getting value from form as `$id` and `$marks`.
i have a js file named as `raw_data.js` 
JS File Content : `window.raw_data = " (6,9) ";`
Now i want that any value that i get from form should cancanate in that JS file in `($id,$marks)` format.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Please clarify

Comment: Hi , I have a form in which if some one enter a Specific answer sheet then automatically Marks will get calculated by a file named process.js and it will return 2 value i.e id and marks . Now i want to automatically insert all these id and marks in raw_data.js file as array (specified in que)

Answer (score 0):

**[LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)** is your solution:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('some title', $id);
window.localStorage.setItem('some title2', $marks);
```

And get it on `raw_data.js`:

```
var $id = window.localStorage.getItem('some title');
var $marks = window.localStorage.getItem('some title2');

window.raw_data = "($id, $marks)";
```

**Edit:** in your code, should be like this:

```
<?php 
if($_POST["marks"] && $_POST["id"]) {
    $marks = $_POST["marks"];
    $id = "ID_" . $_POST["id"];
?>
<script>
    window.localStorage.setItem('some title', $id);
    window.localStorage.setItem('some title2', $marks); 
</script>
<?php
} 
?>
```

Comment: Files are : marks.php
`<?php

if($_POST["marks"] && $_POST["id"]) {
  $marks = $_POST["marks"];
  $id = "ID_" . $_POST["id"];
 window.localStorage.setItem('some title', $id);
window.localStorage.setItem('some title2', $marks);
}

?>`

raw_data.js File

`var $id = window.localStorage.getItem('some title');
var $marks = window.localStorage.getItem('some title2');

window.raw_data = "($id, $marks)";`
@pedram

Comment: @Anuppatel You combined `javascript` and `PHP` ! you should use script tag. / See updated answer.